# Efficient way to process substrings from a string

Tags: c#, string

I have the following string (actually with more elements)

```
string content= "  {
                  element1: one
                  element2: two
                  element3:three
                   }
                   {
                   element1: uno
                   element2: dos
                   element3:tres
                   }";
```

and I need to process this string element by element 
(an element is what is inside a `{` and a `}` , in the above case two elements but it can contain more)

Now, I am thinking of doing the usual `IndexOf` to find `{` and `}` and then extracting the substring one by one.

My question is: is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Seems like you should use a JSON-parser. Don´t re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes, I thought about that. But that would imply deserializing into classes which makes it too complicated for the simple tool I am writing. I was just going for something simpler in the level of string manipulation

Comment: Compared to tring-operations JSON-deserializing **is far** easier, in particular when you have some nested elements as well.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Also I want to learn how to do it if for example the `{`s are　replaced by `[` or other

Comment: Anyway you won´t neccessarily need a class for it, you can of course also de-serialize to a `Dictionary` for example.

Comment: You want something more efficient, but when anyone suggests to use the best way you say: "No, I want string-replace"? So you either want an afficient way or you want to learn how to use string-manipulation. For the latter however I won´t suggest to use some JSON-input.

Comment: I realize also that this is not strictly json, is it? It lacks the ',' between `{}`. Would deserialize work that way?

Comment: Who created this string to begin with? The best way is to do it the way *they* did it (but in reverse of course). If they used a third party library or a standard format, you should too.

Comment: You can always go through the string, one char at a time and build your objects, don't think there can be anymore efficient way of doing it (if efficient mean less resources). Your string also lacks a seperator between 2 internal items, like element1 and element2, suggest you think it more about it and I would suggest go with JSON if you can reformat the source string

Comment: @peeyushsingh  the lack of separator is not due to me. The data was given to me that way

Comment: There are no commas. Is this a line-delimited format? Are the brackets guaranteed to appear on their own lines as well?

Comment: @JohnWu I am assuming the brackets are guaranteed to appear in pairs `{}`

Comment: It depends on your definition of "efficient", ie. what kind of efficiency are you looking for? Fastest code? Smallest amount of memory used? Quickest way to implement? The fastest code is probably going to be using the new Span types, this is one of the things they were added for, string handling without constructing substring objects, but it isn't going to be straightforward to write the code. Since this isn't json, you're going to have to write your own parser for this.

Comment: Also be aware that you usually only get an answer for the question you asked, not for the question you should've asked. If someone posts an answer here that parses the very data in your question, and your first reaction to that would be "Yes, but see, I have this newline in the text in some places, and in some places there are quotes I need to filter out, what about those?", then please make sure you post the COMPLETE format required to be handled.

Comment: @KansaiRobot this looks like invalid JSON. Is it JSON or not? Is it an attempt to create a custom format perhaps?  If it really isn't JSON, the *efficient* way would be to write your own parser that reads the input stream char by char, recognizes tokens etc. How efficient that would be would depend on how good you are at writing parsers. In almost every case it would be more efficient than repeated splitting. I doubt it would be more efficient than JSON.NET itself though - that's a very well written parser

Comment: @KansaiRobot a far better option would be to actually use JSON. If you want to have multiple records in the same file, *don't* use newlines, store only one JSON string per line. That's common with log files, even stream parsing, time series processing etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the data was given to me as what you see. It looks like JSON but since there are no commas separating the {}, it is not (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: @KansaiRobot it's invalid because the fields don't have quotes and the records take multiple lines. You could work around the multiple records issue if there was only a single JSON object per line, by using a StreamReader and ReadLine to read just one record at a time

Comment: @KansaiRobot right now you'd have to decide what the *actual* format is - will there be nested records, arrays, dates, integers? Or is the example you posted all there is? Any chance of `{}:;` appearing in a value?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos right now that is what I have. I will try to check with the source tomorrow if there is any chance of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your format doesn't have any more quirks to it (e.g. delimiters or escape sequences) you can parse that string with a bit of LINQ.

```
    var data = content.Replace("}","").Replace("\r\n","\n").Split('{')
        .Select
        ( 
            block => block.Split('\n')
            .Where
            ( 
                line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)
            )
            .Select
            ( 
                line => line.Split(new char[] {':'}, 2)
            )
            .ToDictionary
            ( 
                fields => fields[0].Trim(), 
                fields => fields[1].Trim()
            )
        )
        .ToList();

    foreach (var list in data)
    {
        foreach (var entry in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
element1=one
element2=two
element3=three
element1=uno
element2=dos
element3=tre
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H0eEUR)

Comment: That would be very expensive unless the string was converted to a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` first. Each string operation in this code generates new temporary strings